# How to get the final command to be executed by sshkit

Tags: rake, capistrano, rake-task, sshkit

I want to create a gem that has de ability to take a task and wrap all commands in another command.

For example, the **capistrano3-unicorn** gem [unicorn:start](https://github.com/tablexi/capistrano3-unicorn/blob/master/lib/capistrano3/tasks/unicorn.rake#L20-L22) task  will execute on the server something like `bundle exec unicorn -c unicorn.rb -E production`, but the execute method is wrapped by a within method, so the command to be executed on the server will be something like `cd /home/deploy/application/myapp/current && bundle exec unicorn -c unicorn.rb -E production`

I want to be able to create a rake task that takes that `unicorn:start` task and wrap it inside another task.

For example if I want to create an upstart config file for the app, I could adds this command to a upstart.conf template and the run `service my-unicorn-app start`

That would be a use case I'm trying to pursue.

In SSHKit formatters the write command is called with a command arg that have what I'm looking for. But I need this at capistrano task level.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand what you are asking. "The command produced by a task"? There is no such thing. Tasks (Rake/Capistrano) can execute multiple commands on the server using SSHKit.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is how to access the exact command that is sent via SSH.  What you're looking for is the [`#command`](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/blob/v1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb#L123) method, on the return value of which you can call `#to_command`.  Since `#command` is a private method, we need to use `#send`.

```
namespace :unicorn
  task :set_restart_command do
    on(roles(:web)) do
      within release_path do
        set(:unicorn_start_command, 
          send(:command, :unicorn, "-c unicorn.rb -E production").to_command)
      end
    end
  end  
end
```

Now, in another task, you can use `fetch(:unicorn_start_command)`